# Database structure two tables with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Okay. I have these two tables I've been struggling with for the entire day. I end up getting something that works in some cases, and others it doesn't. I will therefore explain how the relation of those two tables shall be.

Explanation of the two tables:

objects: This tables job is to hold a lot objects, these objects contain info about it. It contains a name, an image source etc.

House_room1: This table is used for all users in my application. Every user is represented with a `user_id`.

ALL objects which has the same `user_id` as the user logged in shall be printed out. 
 What I mean here is that all the objects that the user has, shall be printed out.
So having these two table examples:

Objects (table)

[image: Object]

house_room1 (table)

[image: house_room1]

So IF user_id=1 PRINT everything from house_room1 with that particular user_id. However theres a **hook!**

These things should only be printed out 1 at a time. and therefore there should be an iterator going through all the objects that the user has.

This is the query I have made so far:

```
$stmt->prepare('SELECT ref_id, x, y, z, src, rotation, link, div_id 
                FROM house_room1
                INNER JOIN objects
                ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id 
                WHERE house_room1.object_id= ? AND house_room1.user_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $i, $GLOBALS['userid_v']); // $i is the iterator
```

However this doesn't do what I expected and its a little hard to predict whats going on. Hope to find some help in here, thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare('SELECT ref_id, x, y, z, src, rotation, link, div_id,objects.object_id 
                                            FROM house_room1
                                            INNER JOIN objects
                                            ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id 
                                            WHERE house_room1.user_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $GLOBALS['userid_v']);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                if ($row['link'] != "") { 
                    echo '<a href="' . $row['link'] . '"> ';
                }
                if ($row['div_id'] != "") { 
                    echo '<a href="#" onClick="' . $row['div_id'] . '"> '; 
                }
                echo '<img src="' . $row['src'] . $row['rotation'] .'.png" id="object' . $row['ref_id'] . '" class="object' . $row['ref_id'] . '" rel="'.$row['rotation'].'"  alt="'.$row['ref_id'].'" style="position:absolute; left:' . $row['x'] . 'px; top:' . $row['y'] . 'px; z-index:'. $row['z'] . ';">'; if ($row['x'] != 0) { echo'</a>'; }
        }
} else {
        echo 'Something went terrible wrong' . $mysqli->error;
}
```

This prints the image but it doesn't have any values on `$row['src']` or either of the `$row` spots?

Comment: what do you mean by *"printed out 1 at a time"*? What is triggering that? One on every user click? One on every row of a table?

Comment: just left join on object_id and use the user_id as you have in the where clause. you dont need the limitation on object_id.

Comment: @A.O. One on every row of a table. Thanks for asking. So it takes out one object at a time.

Comment: @Rufinus I tried what you said, but nothing get printed out on user_id=2. hmm

Comment: how can you have `house_room1.object_id` when you do not identify this column of `object_id` in your initial `SELECT` ?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy uh, do I have to `SELECT` a column in order to use it in the same query? I tried so, but it made no difference to me? Or else I did it wrong?

Comment: `select * ` = all columns when you start doing `select columnA` then you're only getting back `columnA` form your query. And actually @Rufinus is correct in the 2nd comment on this question

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yeah I know, but can't I use a column that I haven't `SELECTED` in a query? I think I've done that before without any problems? uhm well I have updated my post, is this what you mean? And thanks a lot by the way!

Comment: @owwyess No...you don't use `house_room1.object_id` in the select, you just use `object_id` and you also use `objects.object_id`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy however this still prints nothing for user_id=2 ? Which is really weird. Would it help to order it by something?

Comment: try a var_dump of $row to see what is going on, the code looks okay except that the if statements opening the link and closing the link are a little fragile (is it possible for both `link` and `div_id` to be set? will `x` always be set if either `link` or `div_id` is set?)

Comment: @serakfalcon $row returns: `bool(true)` $row['src'] returns `NULL`. Link and div_id can't both be set. Only one of them or none of them. Thanks!

Comment: oh shoot my bad I'm thinking in PDO terms. I will update accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd normally do is return all the results for that user (instead of by object ID), and then use `->fetch_assoc()` to return one row (1 object) at a time, and loop over that. `fetch->()` will return false once there are no more results, so you can use it as the exit condition for a loop.
It's also possible that you're not `execute`-ing the query. And you shouldn't prepare the query inside a loop since that erases the efficiency of the prepared query in the first place.

If you wanted to print out the objects one at a time you should be doing something like

```
$stmt->prepare('SELECT ref_id, x, y, z, src, rotation, link, div_id,objects.object_id 
            FROM house_room1
            INNER JOIN objects
            ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id 
            WHERE house_room1.user_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param($GLOBALS['userid_v']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ref_id,$x,$y,$z,$src,$rotation,$link,$div_id,$objectid);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    // each of the variables in bind_result now reference the current row
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for this code, I should really consider doing it this way, I just want the query to work how it is now at least, and work my way to a better approach later. Thanks!

Comment: but it may not work properly at all depending on how you implement the iterator, that's the problem

Comment: The iterator is in a for loop: `for ($i = 0; $i < $count_total_objects; $i++) {` Maybe I should try your approach while I'm at it anyway. Will take some time for me to get into though

Comment: see, user 2 only has an object id = 1, and object id = 6, so if they have a total count of 2 objects, the iterator will never reach 6. Also, user 1 has 6 objects of id 4, will the iterator print all of them?

Comment: No, it won't! Ah I see dude. But if I want to print a specific `src` or `name` or whatever in your way. Would I then write: `$row['name']` etc? Thanks man

Comment: yeah, exactly. note that it has to be in the `SELECT` statement, so you wouldn't get `name` unless you add it, but `$row['src']` will work.

Comment: would you mind looking at my edit? I can't seem to get the values posted as I wish. Thanks again :)